Execution Python coroutine as background task in new Thread
I've code which looks like this way:
class Service:
    async def publish(file_obj):
        """Sending file_obj to s3"""
    
    def render_pdf(data: dict):
        ""CPU task."""

    async def get_stuff() -> bool:
        """Get data from aio.Redis"""
    
    async def get_data_db() -> SQLAlchemyModel:
        """Get data from DB (like postgres)"""
    
    async def request_to_3rd_api() -> dict:
        """Working with 3rd party API"""

    async def task(data):
        """Task which should be execute as background task. I don't want to get a result of this."""
        # Here is some blocking cpu bound task and also io bound task.
        file_obj = self.render_pdf(data)
        await self.publish(file_obj)   
    
    def sync_task(data):
        asyncio.run(task(data))     

    async def do_smth_useful(self) -> dict | None:
        ""Interface for working with service.
        Make request to 3rd-party API.
        If some stuff exists in Redis then render file with data from 3rd API and save it in S3:     I don't need a result here. Method should return result to caller before this task will be completed.  
        """
        result = await self.request_to_3rd_api()
        db_data = await self.get_data_db()
        data = (result, db_data)
        if := await self.get_stuff():
            threading.Thread(target=sync_task, data).start()
        return result

If i do this under FastAPI I get the RuntimeError:

RuntimeError: Task <Task pending
name='anyio.from_thread.BlockingPortal._call_func'
coro=<BlockingPortal._call_func() running at <path>
/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/from_thread.py:217>
cb=[TaskGroup._spawn.<locals>.task_done() <path>
/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py:661]>
got Future <Future pending cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]>
attached to a different loop got Future <Future pending
cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop

My question is how to correctly execute coroutine in new thread and return a result to client from main thread without waiting when new thread will complete job.
Is it should be sharing event loop for each thread or is it right if I create new event loop for new thread?

I have tried asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe, asyncio.run, asyncio.run_in_executor

I have tried passing event loop from main thread to new one



In addition to the link provided above, please have a look at this answer, as well as this answer and this answer

@Chris Thank you. But seems I have found solution for my case.
I have added getting loop in main thread
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
and then passing it into new thread via coroutine (which I wanted to execute as background task).
Inside coroutine (async def task(data)) I am using
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.publish(file_obj), main_loop)
And it's working as expected now.
